# Efficient way to check whether a month&year of date is present in list of dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I want to check whether value : 30-08-2019 is present in array :['30-08-2019','25-09-2019','03-12-2019'].
This I could achieve by comparing the dates.

```
function isInArray(array, value): boolean {
return !!array.find(item => { return item.getTime() == value.getTime() });
}
```

But if my input date is 31-08-2019,then also the output should be true.
But if it is 31-08-2020, then the output should be false.

So, The check should be on the month and year and not the day.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could for example do something along these lines:

```js
let array = ["30-08-2019", "25-09-2019", "03-12-2019"];

const isMatch = (date) => array.some((e) => e.match(date.slice(2)));

console.log(isMatch("30-08-2019")); // true
console.log(isMatch("31-08-2019")); // true
console.log(isMatch("31-08-2020")); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just check the month and the year, and if you can be sure that there are leading zeroes in all dates, you can simply use a substring of the date; cut off the initial three characters, which are the day and the hyphen.

If the leading zero might be omitted, you can split the string into components on the hyphen, and compare the second and third element of the resulting array instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare month and year like that:

```
function isInArray(array, value): boolean {
return !!array.find(item => { return ((item.getMonth() == value.getMonth())&&( item.getYear() == value.getYear())) });
}
```